# angular md-tabs not showing in ios

Tags: html, css, angular-material

I am working on a search part (web based system), and I am using angular material(1) in designing, all works fine on Android devices but when we're testing in IOS, both in safari and chrome, md-tabs are not showing, only the header and bottom parts are showing [totally not showing when clicking the button for pop up, the entire tabs are not showing], I tried to search in the internet, visiting the angularjs docu in github but it seems that it was solved in their previous release (way back 2015) and now I am using the latest release, anyone have any idea or reason behind this problem?. Much appreciated if anyone knows or can give any idea on this.

```
<md-dialog  class="md-fullscreen-dialog">
<form name="searchForm" ng-submit="submit()">
    <md-toolbar>
        <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
            <h2>Search Vehicle</h2>
            <span flex></span>
            <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="cancel()">
                <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/ic_close_24px.svg" aria-label="Close dialog"></md-icon>
            </md-button>
        </div>
    </md-toolbar>

    <md-dialog-content style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
        <md-tabs md-border-bottom md-dynamic-height md-selected="tabPage">
            <md-tab label="Filters">
                <md-content layout-gt-sm="row" layout="row" layout-xs="column">
                        <md-content id="filterArea" class="md-padding">
                            //content here
                        </md-content>
                        <md-content id="searchArea" class="md-padding">
                            //content here
                        </md-content>
                </md-content>
            </md-tab>
            <md-tab label="Results" md-on-select="tab2Selected()" ng-disabled="!isQuickSearch()">
                    <md-content class="md-padding">
                        <kendo-grid k-scope-field="kVGrid"
                                    id="VGrid"
                                    k-options="src"
                                    k-auto-bind="false">
                        </kendo-grid>
                    </md-content>
                </md-tab>
        </md-tabs>
    </md-dialog-content>
    <md-dialog-actions layout="row">
        <span flex></span>
        <input class="md-button md-primary diagbutton" type="submit" value="Search" />
        <md-button class="diagbutton" style="margin-left:1.5em;" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</md-button>
    </md-dialog-actions>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any way to inspect the source code on the devices ?

If so, try to find the tabs and inspect them. You should see where they went (maybe outside the page because of a `left`property, for instance), and also see the applied style.